# How to include third party JARs in Android library AAR, without code

Tags: android-studio, jar, aar

If build an aar that contains a third-party jar, the code will be included.

It's included in `classes.jar`, but I do not want this.

I use only part of the jar's api, 
which causes a crash when another app uses the same jar.

error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method BC()[B in class Lcom/Encryption/Encrypt/API; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.Encryption.Encrypt.API' appears in /data/app/kr.co.MyApp-1/base.apk:classes8.dex)
```

I want the jar used by aar to be saved as `aar/libs/myjar.jar`

This page says it's possible.
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html